# Additional image files with some random hash?

Tags: image, hash, prestashop, thumbnails

I found out that in my PrestaShop (1.6.1.4) images are visible only for logged out users. After login, images dissapear (frontend). What more, when logged out, the image url is (Example):

https://www.e-ryneczek.pl/2346-tm_home_default/arbuz.jpg

After login, the same product image url become:

https://www.e-ryneczek.pl/2346-tm_home_default-X6sI2y9CbJ/arbuz.jpg

The only difference is that after login, PrestaShop adds this: -X6sI2y9CbJ inside image url.

---

After further investigations I found out, that some of images (about 10%) really got additional physical file with the same ending on server! This is not memory efficient, as those are the same images (duplicates). So few questions:

1) **Why is PrestaShop changing the image url for logged in users?**

2) **Why it's not resolved in htaccess**, but there are REALLY physical files with that strange "hash"

3*) Any ideas, why those "hash" images are not created in all cases and my logged-in front user don't see almost any images? This question is not exactly about system or programming purposes, so if this is not the place to ask, sorry about that.

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks for comment. I have done grep -r through all PrestaShop files and Database. This is 100% PrestaShop problem. This strange hash appears in:

- database under "WATERMARK_HASH"
- classes/Image.php
- classes/Link.php

Full list (under terminal):

```
cd YourPrestaShopDirectory
grep -r WATERMARK_HASH
```

Comment: Prestashop does not do this by default. Could be some module or an override that's doing this. You might wanna search the project files for this hash string and see if there's a code that appends it to the image links.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. I was suspicious to. Could You please provide this comment as an answer? I will accept it, and upvote. I'm going to do a grep over all files in presta and find out what is that. Great idea, it solves my problem perfectly.

Comment: I found this one in database under WATERMARK_HASH. Also in classes/Image.php. This is 100% PrestaShop problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said it's not a default Prestashop problem, however there is a module made by Prestashop called Watermark.

Probably you have that module installed and in it's config you have `Logged-in customers see images without watermark` set to `No`.

If you use watermarks on images then you should regenerate images under `Preferences -> Images` at the bottom of the page so that all images also get watermarked copy generated.

If not, you can disable that module.